# Unable to access container's web server via 127.0.0.1 but works with localhost

Tags: docker, networking, containers, macos-big-sur, docker-network

I'm running into an issue with Docker on macOS Big Sur where I can't access any server/API running inside a container by using 127.0.0.1. But it seems to work when I use localhost.

The following what I'm running to demonstrate my problem

I start an nginx container like so:

```
docker run --name mynginx1 -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

then attempt to access it via 127.0.0.1:

```
❯ curl 127.0.0.1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

but if I access via localhost, it works:

```
❯ curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what my `/etc/hosts` looks like:

```
#
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost

# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I also attempted to start the container by explicitly defining host:

```
❯ docker run --name mynginx1 -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 -d nginx
```

but this failed as well :(

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It works for me with both localhost and 127.0.0.1